# How to return Neo4j OGM entities in GraphJSON format instead of tree format for visualization?

Tags: json, d3.js, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I am getting JSON data from Neo4j OGM (Object Graph Mapping) in nested-tree like format.
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550

But for visualizing complex graphs, I need to get the JSON data in the following graphJSON format.
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

i.e.,with nodes and links separated.

> This is for visualizing data from Neo4j using d3.js visualization
>   after performing various operations using Java.

Answer (score 1):

If your data json is in the format defined in http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550
and you want to make it into the json format defined in http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045.

Do something like this:

```
//this will make the nodes
function flatten(root) {
    var nodes = [];
    var i = 0;

    function recurse(node) {
        if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
        if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
        nodes.push(node);
    }

    recurse(root);
    return nodes;
}
//Here root is the json defined in http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550
nodes = flatten(root);
//this will return the links in the desired format
links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);
//check console for output
console.log(nodes)
console.log(links)
```

Yes you can change data dynamically there are many examples on this.
Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/Lrud9gsr/)
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Cyril. Actually I wanted to do this conversion in JAVA side.

Comment: Is there any API to do this from JAVA side?  I am now doing as you mentioned, but I need to pass properties of relations also to client side. Also there are loops in the graph. So I find it difficult to visualize data from treeJSON format.

Comment: Sorry i don't know how to do the same on JAVA...:(

Answer (score 1):

There is documentation on how to do it in the examples linked from:

- http://neo4j.com/developer/java

The examples are in:

- https://github.com/neo4j-examples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=java